# Do I need to explicitly create an ID in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to determine if Rails has a built-in primary key ID for each database entry or if, when running `rails generate` I have to explicitly define an ID such as `id:integer`. So far I've run across a lot of posts asking how to change the primary key behavior or how to create multi-column indexes but nothing stating how Rails handles the primary key by default if, in fact, it does.

If it is simply a matter of using `id:integer` when running `rails generate` is there anything else necessary to ensure the column is used as the primary key? I've seen `:primary => true` mentioned but little in the way of explanation on why it is included in any particular example. Usually it is part of an explanation that deals with the aforementioned multi-column indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `do not` need to explicitly define column `id` in your migration as Rails would take care of that. For every table that you create Rails would create an id:integer column as a primary key. Rails doesn't show it in `migration file` or `schema.rb` but you can go to `rails dbconsole` and check the schema.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Follow-up for sanity: When Rails takes care of it is uniqueness also ensured?

Comment: As soon as the timeout expires. ;)

Comment: Thats fine. No Problem..:)